# Unexpected character after malloc

Tags: c

I have some codes like that :

```
        ............                    
        char *old = NULL ;
        char *new = NULL;
        char *b1 = malloc(strlen(b) + 1);
        memcpy(b1,b,strlen(b) + 1);
        char *c;
        for(c = strtok_r(b1,"=",&saveptr3) ; c != NULL ; c = strtok_r(NULL,"=",&saveptr3)){
            fprintf(f,"c: %s\n",c);
            if(fl == 0) {                       
                fprintf(f,"old1: %s\n",old);    
                old = malloc(strlen(c) + 3 );
                fprintf(f,"old2: %s\n",old);
                strcat(old,"=:");
                strcat(old,c);
                fprintf(f,"old3: %s\n",old);    
                fl++;
            } else {
                new = malloc(strlen(c) + 1);
                strcat(new,"=");
                strcat(new,c);
                if(!sql) {
                    sql = malloc(strlen(first_part) + 1);                       
                    sql = str_replace(first_part,old,new);
                } else {
                    sql = str_replace(sql,old,new);
                }   
            }
       .....................
```

You can see , I have `old` variable ,`malloc` and using `strcat` to append some text to it

But when I printf it ,I get an unexpected character ( ▒▒X▒8) after issue a `malloc` :

```
old1: (null)

old2: ▒▒X▒8

old3: ▒▒X▒8=:C1
```

I using `free` to clear `old` variable after using ,but my program hang forever ,I have to  force `kill` it

Please tell me what wrong .

Comment: Your allocation to `sql` and the subsequent reassignment will most likely not work as expected.

Comment: could you explain it more detail ,I'm new to C , thanks

Comment: First you make `sql` contain the value returned by `malloc`, then you make `sql` contain the value returned by `str_replace` and thereby loosing the original value. It's like doing e.g. `int a; a = 5; a = 23;`. The second assignment makes you loose the value from the first assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you request memory with `malloc`, it is unitialized (i.e. can contain
random data). 
Use e.g. `calloc` if you want to have it initalized to zero.

This is the reason why

```
           old = malloc(strlen(c) + 3 );
           fprintf(f,"old2: %s\n",old);
```

prints only random data. You need at least set `old[0]='\0';` after the `malloc` call.